# how do i specify libraries's path to cmake which are used by target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake, linker, libcurl, ld

I have some codebase which has `cmake` build system .while building iam getting an error as below

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
```

below is the sample `cmakelist.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
project(oci_object_test)

set(IB_HOME /home/user/sample_cmake/usr/lib)

include_directories(${LIB_HOME}/include)
link_directories(${LIB_HOME}/lib64)

link_directories(/home/user/sample_cmake/usr/lib/lib64)
link_directories(/home/user/)

set(SOURCES
        sample.cpp
)

add_executable(demo ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(demo curl openssl)
```

for the above `cmakelist.txt` below is the `link.txt` generated by cmake

```
/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/demo.dir/sample.cpp.o  -o demo  -L/home/user/sample_cmake/usr/lib/lib64  -L/home/user -rdynamic -lcurl -lopenssl -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/sample_cmake/usr/lib/lib64:/home/user
```

this issue is due to `-lcurl` getting added in `link.txt` generated by cmake . if i remove `-lcurl` from `link.txt` manually and build ,build will get success with no linker error . So is there any way i can get rid off this `-lcurl` in `link.txt` or is it possible to define -lcurl path where it actual libcurl present ( for example suppose libcurl present inside `/usr/curl_path/curl`)  so that cmake could generate link.txt as below?

```
/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/demo.dir/sample.cpp.o  -o demo  -L/home/user/sample_cmake/usr/lib/lib64  -L/home/user -rdynamic /usr/curl_path/curl -lopenssl -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/sample_cmake/usr/lib/lib64:/home/user
```

i know i can define `libucrl` path directly as below which will solve my issue ,

```
target_link_libraries(demo /usr/curl_path/curl openssl)
```

but iam looking for something like `SET`  or any other `cmake environment variable` which i can define inside toolchain.cmake file so that `cmakelist.txt` is untouched ,`in simple words how do i specify those  libraries's path to cmake which are going use inside target_link_libraries`

Comment: You'll have to look through the CMakeLists.txt files to see where the curl library is being linked. Look for `link_libraries()` or `target_link_libraries()` commands in the CMake files, that may contain `curl` or `-lcurl`. It is hard to suggest anything definitive without seeing the CMake files themselves...

Comment: @ squareskittles i have added sample cmakelist.txt and full description of the problem please look into it

Comment: CMake does not automagically links libcurl (or any other library) to your program. You have (or had) somewhere in your CMakeLists.txt a request to link this library. In short: @squareskittles is right. Either you show your full cmake scripts or you find it on your own.

Comment: how do i specify  libraries's path to cmake which are used by target_link_libraries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue can be solved by two methods (first method is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885402/8493946))

second method is by adding below two lines of code to your `cmakelist.txt` file before calling `target_link_directories`

```
add_library( curl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET curl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CURL_LIBRARY}")
```

where `CURL_LIBRARY` is the path  for `libcurl.so` specified in `toolchain.cmake`
unfortunately i didn't find any solution to solve this issue without touching `cmakelist.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If your CMake version is less than 3.12, you need to use this old method. See:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindCURL.html

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(program)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

if (CURL_FOUND)
    add_executable(program main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(program ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(program PRIVATE ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

There is a new method for CMake 3.12 and later using imported targets. See the new  alternative [FindCurl](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindCURL.html).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(program)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

if (CURL_FOUND)
    add_executable(program main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(program CURL::libcurl)
endif()
```